How can I get full bash completion in external (:!) commands?
If I start typing an external command such as :!gi and then press Tab, vim will autocomplete the command name ("git"). But if I enter :!git comm and press Tab, I get no completions - vim doesn't provide tab completion for anything except the name ("git") of the command itself.
If I enter git comm in Bash and press Tab, I will get completion for all of git's subcommands, options, etc.
Is there a way to get this level of command completion for running external commands from vim? (To be clear I'm looking for a general solution, not just for the git command).

Unfortunately, Bash doesn't easily expose its programmable completion functionality to be consumed by other programs. But if you're ok with a rather ugly looking solution, using the following in my .vimrc has been working very well for me:
Note the hardcoded path source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion in the shell script - this works on Fedora, but it may be different for other distros. Check your /etc/profile to see where it gets sourced from.
command! -nargs=+ -complete=custom,s:BashCmdComp ExtCmd :!<args>
cnoremap ! <c-r>=getcmdpos() == 1 ? "ExtCmd " : "!"<cr>

func s:BashCmdComp(arglead, vimcmdline, vimcursorpos)
    " strip vim command
    let l:cmdline = substitute(a:vimcmdline, '^\S\+ \(.*\)', '\1', "g")
    let l:cursorpos = 1 + a:vimcursorpos - (strlen(a:vimcmdline) - strlen(l:cmdline))

    " remove everything after the cursor so that completion can always act on the last word
    let l:cmdline = l:cmdline[:l:cursorpos]

    if count(l:cmdline, " ") == 0
        return system("compgen -A command " . a:arglead)
    end

    let l:cmdname = substitute(l:cmdline, '^\(\S\+\) .*$', '\1', "")
    let l:scriptlines =<< trim eval END
        __print_completions() {{
            printf '%s\n' "${{COMPREPLY[@]% }}"
        }}

        # This is the path on Fedora, it may be different for other distros
        source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
        _completion_loader {l:cmdname}

        COMP_WORDS=({l:cmdline})
        COMP_LINE='{l:cmdline}'
        COMP_POINT={l:cursorpos}
        COMP_CWORD=$((${{#COMP_WORDS[@]}} - 1))
        [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 0 ] && COMP_CWORD=1
        $(complete -p {l:cmdname} | sed 's/^.*-F \([^ ][^ ]*\).*/\1/')
        __print_completions
    END

    let l:output = trim(system(join(l:scriptlines, "\n")))
    if l:output != ""
        return l:output
    else
        return join(getcompletion(a:arglead, "file"), "\n")
    endif
endfunc


Some explanation of the shell in the answer would improve it
